# ReactiveUI + Portable Class Library?

Tags: wpf, nuget, reactiveui

I'm porting a WPF app over to Windows Store app.  I have some view models that I would like to put into a Portable Class Library.  That code uses reactiveui framework.  I created the library and I use nuget package manager to add reactiveui to the project.  I get this:

`Could not install package 'reactiveui-platforms 5.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+wp80+win', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Is this really an unsupported configuration or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReactiveUI-Platforms` is specifically only the platform-specific code. You need to just reference `ReactiveUI-Core` in your PCL and reference `ReactiveUI-Platforms` in your WPF and Windows Store apps, and everything should work.

Comment: I am doing same thing, according to your answer Now I am trying to add reactiveui-core nuget package to my portable class library project but still getting message: Adding'reactiveui-core 5.5.1' to PortableClassLibraryDemo.  Could not install package 'reactiveui-core 5.5.1' you are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+sl50' but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: ReactiveUI 5.0 isnt compatible with SL5